# two dimensional identifier that is circular?

Tags: math, vector, ids

i need an identifier value that is circular when lerping to the next one. Example:

`0,1,2,3`

When lerping form any id to the next one in the row, we always get a value between both ids. Except for 3: when lerping to the next id (back to zero) it will be lerped through all ids.

So what i am searching for is something two dimesional for example:

`(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0)`

When learping from (1,0) to (0,0) it will lerp fine.

How do I warp this in a function or loop to convert for examle 0,1,2,3,4 to two-dimensional ids?

Comment: I am not sure I understamd what you are looking for, nor why 2-dim ids should be used..

Comment: I share @Nikos' confusion. Isn't this better handled in an appropriate lerp function?

Comment: What is "lerping"? A typo or something from outside of my limited vocabulary?

Comment: @Yunnosch, the OP uses the neologism "*lerping*" in the sense of executing the `lerp` function which linearly interpolates two values. So the OP by *lerping* means *linearly interpolating*

Comment: @NikosM. So I am excused from not knowing. But definitly a good and plausible explanation. I had the feeling that no typo could explain it...

Comment: Please add an example sample input + output that is not trivial. Also you want iterate upwards or in direction resulting in more or less ids?

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for a function that takes a number `k` from 0 to N-1 and returns a point on a circle? That's what the trigonometric functions sine and cosine do by definition.

You would transform the number `k` into the point (x, y) where:

```
x = cos(k*360°/N)
y = sin(k*360°/N)
```

(Note that most software libraries take the input in radians and not degrees, if that's your case you would replace 360 degrees with 2*pi, or use a built-in "toRadians" function)

Comment: nice, but does not result in linear interpolation, if this is what the OP wants. My feeling is that the OP wants "modulo" linear interpolation, if such a term can be used

Comment: @NikosM. my educated guess is  `increment modulo` to obtain all `(N+1)` dimensional ids between  two `N` dimensional ids ...

Comment: The op writes they want a "two dimensional id" specifically. I guess we'll know if this approach fits their purpose if/when they come back.